# Two python3 interpreters on win10 cause misunderstanding

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

I used win10. When I installed Visual Studio2017, I configure the Python3 environment. And then after half year I installed Anaconda(Python3) in another directory. Now I have two interpreters in different directories.

> Now, no matter in what IDE I code the codes, after I save it and double click it in the directory, the Python File is run by the interpreter configured by VS2017.

Why do I know that? I use *sys.path* to get to know it. But when I use VS2017 to run the code, it shows no mistake. The realistic example is that I *pip install requests* in cmd, then I *import* it in a Python File. Only when I double click it, the *Traceback* says I don't have this module. In other cases it works well.

> So, how to change the default python interpreter of the cmd.exe?

Comment: Change the order of executables in `PATH`

Comment: I'd like to add, that, generally, you would not want to use anaconda python executable outside conda environments. Having sandboxes allows you to keep your system (main) python clean of the development packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the interpreter order of the python in the PATH is enough.
If you want to use python further more, I suggest you to use virtual environment tools like `pipenv` to control your python interpreters and modules.